# How to identify CC and CV mode for given readings of load resistance, voltage and corresponding load current?

Tags: dc, constant-current, constant-voltage

I want know which is the correct way to approach problems where we have to identify CC and CV mode.

Let us consider a question -

> For various load resistors, connected across \$Channel-1\$ of the DC power supply the following table is
> obtained-

| **\$R_L\$** | Output Voltage (V) | Load current (A) | Mode of Operation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| \$\infty\$ | 5.00 | 0.00 | a |
| 100 | 5.00 | 0.05 | b |
| 200 | 5.00 | 0.25 | c |

Now we have to determine what modes are a, b, and c

---

I have done this problem in two ways-

First: Since V is constant and load current is changing with values of load resistance so, a,b, and c must all be in CV mode. But here I am not considering the fact that in the third reading load is drawing more current than the ratio \$V/R_L\$.

Second: Is based on this text that I have recently read, here they have given the graph-

[image]

I will plot the values of V and I and see which operation line it is following(CV or CC), but for the third reading, we find that \$R_L\$ is greater than \$R_c= V/R_L \$, it will lie on CV mode line. Checking for first and second reading as well, I get all a, b, and c in CV mode.

---

So, which method is more correct and general such that I can apply it on all such problems?
Please let me know if the second method is correct approach or not.

Also what do they mean by this?-

> A power supply will operate in constant
> voltage (CV) mode provided the load
> does not require more current than the
> current limit setting.

Link for the image source for reference- [Fundamentals of DC Power suppy](https://assets.testequity.com/te1/Documents/pdf/10-DC-Power-Supply-Fundamentals.pdf)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because homework needs an attempt at a solution

Comment: @VoltageSpike♦  I have attempted the question, even the answer is correct and I am asking if the way I am thinking is correct or not. You need to re-evaluate your judgement.

Comment: I have mentioned in the very first line of the question, what I want to know, and question is just an example.

Comment: The voltage is 5 V in each case so it's constant, so ...

Comment: Your second method is just the graphical representation of the first one.

Comment: First task is to spot the mistake in the table.

Comment: @Mirae No problem then! Since you've already done the work, just edit the question with your attempt. Let me know and I'll reopen the question as soon as I can. Also please provide a source for the image. Thanks

Comment: Tip: inline MathJAX uses `\$` opening and closing markdown unlike some of the other SE sites which just use `$`.

Comment: @VoltageSpike Alright, I have made the required edits. Please check it.

Comment: You still have an error in the table. Double-check your numbers.

Comment: @Transistor They are correct from my part, I have taken the table from one of my exam questions.

Comment: How much current will a 200 ohm resistor draw from a 5 V supply?

Comment: @Transistor that should be 0.025, but here notice that load is drawing more current, that was the reason I am not confident with the first approach. Since I read the attached text, I applied the second approach, where such condition is represented by  R_L > R_C .

Comment: If it's drawing more than 0.025 A at 5 V then it's not 200 ohms. ***V = IR*** has to apply.

Comment: @Transistor Say the value of current is 0.025A for same values of V and R, so do you think we need second method? Or is second method any useful?

Comment: @Mirae, I think you are a victim of an error in the table (0.25A is wrong). Your understanding of CC and CV seems to be good, but by assuming the exam question must be valid, you have been led on a wild goose chase. I admire that you've forged ahead trying to resolve this though.

Comment: @SimonFitch If that's the case, its good. The condition matched so well with the text. I will confirm from the professor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in your table. 200 Ω on a 5 V supply will draw 25 mA (0.025 A), not 0.25 A.If it's drawing more than 0.025 A at 5 V then it's not 200 ohms. ***V = IR*** has to apply.

> Say the value of current is 0.025A for same values of V and R, so do you think we need second method? Or is second method any useful?

If the voltage is constant then you haven't hit the current limit yet so no further analysis is required. You haven't given us the CC limit and we can't calculated it from the table so we can't calculate RC so you can't do the graphical analysis.

> Also what do they mean by this?-

> > A power supply will operate in constant voltage (CV) mode provided the load does not require more current than the current limit setting.

They just mean exactly that.

[image]

*Figure 1. A lab power supply. Image source: Instek.*

If you have access to a lap supply such as shown above you can set a voltage limit and current limit on the device. You can then connect load resistors and see the effect.

For example: If you set U = 5 V and I = 100 mA then \$ R_C = \frac U I = \frac {5} {0.1} =50\ \Omega \$. For any load > 50 Ω the PSU will be able to run at constant voltage (5 V) and the load will draw < 100 mA. At any load < 50 Ω the load will draw 100 mA but the voltage will drop. At 50 Ω the load will draw 100 mA and the voltage will *just* hold steady at 5 V.

Comment: Can you also mention one such example for constant current mode condition? I am a bit confused.

Comment: I did. "At any load < 50 Ω the load will draw 100 mA but the voltage will drop."

Comment: You did, I misread. It's clear now.